# pd.cut with datetime IntervalIndex as bins

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

From followig code, I am expecting these timestamps to be binned into periods provided through an `IntervalIndex`.
Unfortunately, I only get `NaN` returned.
Please, what is the trouble?

```py
import pandas as pd

# Test data
ts = [pd.Timestamp('2022/03/01 09:00'),
      pd.Timestamp('2022/03/01 10:00'),
      pd.Timestamp('2022/03/01 10:30'),
      pd.Timestamp('2022/03/01 15:00')]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(len(ts)), 'ts': ts})
# Test
bins = pd.interval_range(pd.Timestamp('2022/03/01 08:00'),
                         pd.Timestamp('2022/03/01 16:00'),
                         freq='2H',
                         closed="left")
row_labels = pd.cut(df["ts"], bins)
```

I am expecting the result to be:

```py
[2022-03-01 08:00:00, 2022-03-01 10:00:00)
[2022-03-01 10:00:00, 2022-03-01 12:00:00)
[2022-03-01 10:00:00, 2022-03-01 12:00:00)
[2022-03-01 14:00:00, 2022-03-01 16:00:00)
```

But I only get `NaN`.

```py
row_labels
Out[37]: 
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
Name: ts, dtype: category
Categories (4, interval[datetime64[ns], left]): [ <
                                                 [2022-03-01 08:00:00, 2022-03-01 10:00:00) <
                                                 [2022-03-01 10:00:00, 2022-03-01 12:00:00) <
                                                 [2022-03-01 12:00:00, 2022-03-01 14:00:00) <
                                                 [2022-03-01 14:00:00, 2022-03-01 16:00:00)]
```

Please, what is the trouble?
Thanks for your help.
Bests,

Comment: This seems buggy probably should be reported.

Comment: @ScottBoston, Reported where?.. Open an issue on [Pandas github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues)?

Comment: Yes.   That is correct @VladimirFokow.

Comment: [This issue on GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/48083#issue-1338463791)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Very interesting...

```py
pd.cut(df['ts'].to_list(), bins)
```

produces the expected result

```py
[[2022-03-01 08:00:00, 2022-03-01 10:00:00), 
 [2022-03-01 10:00:00, 2022-03-01 12:00:00), 
 [2022-03-01 10:00:00, 2022-03-01 12:00:00), 
 [2022-03-01 14:00:00, 2022-03-01 16:00:00)]

Categories (4, interval[datetime64[ns], left]): [
                [2022-03-01 08:00:00, 2022-03-01 10:00:00) < 
                [2022-03-01 10:00:00, 2022-03-01 12:00:00) < 
                [2022-03-01 12:00:00, 2022-03-01 14:00:00) < 
                [2022-03-01 14:00:00, 2022-03-01 16:00:00)]
```

### BUT!

```py
pd.cut(df['ts'].to_numpy(), bins)
```

```py
[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]

Categories (4, interval[datetime64[ns], left]): [
                [2022-03-01 08:00:00, 2022-03-01 10:00:00) < 
                [2022-03-01 10:00:00, 2022-03-01 12:00:00) < 
                [2022-03-01 12:00:00, 2022-03-01 14:00:00) < 
                [2022-03-01 14:00:00, 2022-03-01 16:00:00)]
```

### What??

Why does it work with a list but DOESN'T work with `np.ndarray` or `pd.Series`?

---

ALSO :

```py
bins_dt_index = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('2022/03/01 08:00'),
                              pd.Timestamp('2022/03/01 16:00'),
                              freq='2H')
bins_dt_index
```

```py
DatetimeIndex(['2022-03-01 08:00:00', '2022-03-01 10:00:00',
               '2022-03-01 12:00:00', '2022-03-01 14:00:00',
               '2022-03-01 16:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='2H')
```

```py
pd.cut(df['ts'].to_list(), bins_dt_index, right=False)
```

produces

> ```py
> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Timestamp'
> ```

while

```py
pd.cut(df['ts'], bins_dt_index, right=False)
```

produces the expected result!

```py
0    [2022-03-01 08:00:00, 2022-03-01 10:00:00)
1    [2022-03-01 10:00:00, 2022-03-01 12:00:00)
2    [2022-03-01 10:00:00, 2022-03-01 12:00:00)
3    [2022-03-01 14:00:00, 2022-03-01 16:00:00)
Name: ts, dtype: category

Categories (4, interval[datetime64[ns], left]): [
                [2022-03-01 08:00:00, 2022-03-01 10:00:00) < 
                [2022-03-01 10:00:00, 2022-03-01 12:00:00) < 
                [2022-03-01 12:00:00, 2022-03-01 14:00:00) < 
                [2022-03-01 14:00:00, 2022-03-01 16:00:00)]
```

So `DatetimeIndex` works with `np.ndarray` and `pd.Series` but DOESN'T work with a list!

And `IntervalIndex` - vice versa!

Shouldn't they all work the same? I mean, [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) clearly states that `x` can be a 1-dimensional `array-like`.

**It would be great if someone explained why this happens !**

Comment: This seems buggy.

Comment: Many thanks for this detailed investigation! Ok will use DatetimeIndex for the moment.